# Evaluation / Simulation of existing python program

Tags: python, simulation, evaluation, overhead, simpy

I implemented a distributed monitoring solution which should be analyzed. Therefore it would be good to scale number of monitoring agents and to evaluate the resulting overhead (CPU, Memory, Disk, Network) on each host (or network). Unfortunately, I have not enough physical nodes. Therefore I made primarily attempts with *mininet*, however I ran into negativ timing and scheduling effects. In addition, CPU or memory usage on a host is difficult to investigate during emulation on only one physical host.

Hence, I tried *simpy*. But I'm not able to monitor CPU, memory, disk and network usage of processes. Is there any possibility to do so? It would be good to have a soultion for evaluation which does not depend on host resources and correct timing, like a simulation does. But I'm not sure if *simpy* is a good decision or how this tool could provide this.

Comment: Some of the monitoring tools are operating system specific, so it would help if you said which OS you are using.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Check out the `resource` module in the standard library, specifically `getrusage`.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html.  Unfortunately it doesn't cover everything you need, but its a start.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. But is it possible to use it in conjunction with _simpy_? Or does that affect the values? I would like to evaluate a distributed scenario on only one physical host without timing and scheduling effects.

Comment: try [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) as well

Comment: Sorry, I don't know `simpy`.  `psutil` is very good, but it is not part of the standard library.

Comment: If you're going to repost your questions, please don't flag them for moderator attention.

Comment: Sorry for that @BoltClock . _simpy_ is a event discrete simulation for Python. My plan is to run my distributed program in a bigger scale and to evaluate overhead.